# First Char of any words in a sentences

Tags: php, smarty

I would like to extract any first char of any word inside a sentence like:

```
Full time become FT
Part time become PT
Contractor become C
Temp become T
```

Is that possible in smarty PHP and how? I have {$listing.EmployementType}.

Comment: how did you assign $listing.EmploymentType in php?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat functional way to do it:

```
function firstLetter($word) {
    return uc($word[0]);
}

$result = implode('', array_map('firstLetter', explode(' ', $sentence)));
```

https://www.php.net/array_map

https://www.php.net/explode

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

**Edit:** alternatively,

```
$result = '';
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $result .= uc($word[0]);
}
```

Actually shorter and probably more readable, but less fun haha.

**Edit 2**: sorry, didn't realise smarty was a requirement of the question. I'll just leave this here in case someone else looking for a pure php solution stumbles upon this question.

Comment: @Maion ah sorry I'm not familiar with smarty and didn't realise it was a requirement of the question.

Comment: no worries no worries, that code would work on php though and sometimes its good to just do all the coding in php and displaying in smarty..

Answer (score 1):

```
{assign var=firstWord value=" "|explode:"$listing.EmployementType"}
```

then access the first word by $firstWord[0]..
you might want to look in to it further..
http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=6581&sid=f8cc8323a968506f305c803e94f522f1

Comment: I need 1st character of each word. Based on your code, is that {assign var=firstletter value=" "|explode:"$listing.EmployementType|substr:0:1"}   {$firstletter[0]}{$firstletter[1]}??

Comment: @alouty im a lil bit confused, do you want the first letter or the first word?

Comment: First Letters. Full time become FT.

Comment: @Alouty i've never done that using smarty alone that might be bit complex for smarty, it would be better if we do the coding in php, if you need help with that just give us a shout ^_^

Comment: Is that {assign var=firstWord value=" "|explode:"$listing.EmployementType"} - {$firstWord[0]|substr:0:1}{$firstWord[1]|substr:0:1}??

Comment: @Alouty: You can create a custom function using the logic from CrazySheep's answer and use that in Smarty. Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl) for examples

Comment: Actually I don't know how to bring php functions into smarty tpl file. I also don't know where I should put the php function although it is best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a smarty plugin that fits your requirements. In this case, a modifier plugin.
If you know some basic php it's very easy: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins